# How to Encrypt Column Data in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, encryption

I tried convert column data to  new encrpted data.I get this error

```
  Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of DecryptByKey function.
```

Query :

```
SELECT ID,FirmName,newDeviceID=CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),DecryptByKey(DeviceID))

FROM Table1
```

DeviceID is int.

Comment: DecryptByKey function decrypts data by using a symmetric key. First argument in this function is data that has been encrypted with the key and is varbinary.So error is stating the same ..you cant pass an int. You can refer to link below for more information:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181860(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert column data to new encrpted data you can do something like below:

```
create table Table1( id int, FirmName varchar(10),DeviceID int);
insert into Table1 values (1,'Firm1','123');

--If there is no master key, create one now. 
IF NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE symmetric_key_id = 101)
    CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY 
    PASSWORD = '23987hxJKL969#ghf0%94467GRkjg5k3fd117r$$#1946kcj$n44nhdlj'
GO

CREATE CERTIFICATE Table1
   WITH SUBJECT = 'Table1 Device ID';
GO

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01
    WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
    ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Table1;
GO


-- Create a column in which to store the encrypted data.
ALTER TABLE Table1
    ADD EncryptedDeviceID varbinary(128); 
GO

-- Open the symmetric key with which to encrypt the data.
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01
   DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Table1;

-- Encrypt the value in column DeviceID with symmetric 
-- key SSN_Key_01. Save the result in column EncryptedDeviceID.
UPDATE Table1
SET EncryptedDeviceID = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SSN_Key_01'), convert(nvarchar,DeviceID));
GO

-- Verify the encryption.
-- First, open the symmetric key with which to decrypt the data.
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key_01
   DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Table1;
GO

-- Now list the original ID, the encrypted ID, and the 
-- decrypted ciphertext. If the decryption worked, the original
-- and the decrypted ID will match.
SELECT ID,FirmName, EncryptedDeviceID
    AS 'Encrypted ID Number',
    CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey(EncryptedDeviceID)) 
    AS 'Decrypted ID Number'
    FROM Table1;
GO
```

For more information you can refer to following link:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331(v=sql.100).aspx

Hope this helps!!